# Laravel - Mark value in a selection/option field as selected after comparison with an entry in array from database - Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, drop-down-menu

I passed an array of production locations from the controller to the edit.blade.php view. In this edit file there is a Select Option field with three entries.

In the edit.blade.php I also have a box with different products (from a products array) displayed in rows. These products can be clicked individually. After clicking on a product, I would like to compare the already entered value for production location from the product array with the already generated select option field. If they match, the field in the production locations array should be changed as selected.

All via Javascript without POST or Ajax since the data is on the page ready to be accessed.
Here is my solution for fiddlingaway:

```
<select class="form-control m-bot15" id="ProduktionsortSelect"  
  name="Produktionsort" data-placeholder="dadada">
<option id="">----</option>
@foreach ( $data['produktionsort'] as $produkteOrt )
   <option value="{{$produkteOrt->Ort}}" id="{{$produkteOrt->Ort}}">     
   {{$produkteOrt->Ort}}</option>
 @endForeach  
/select>  
In javascript then:
<script>

var jqueryarray; 
var dasProdukt;
var currentElementID;
var elementArr = document.getElementsByClassName("flexRadioDefault");

//alert(elementArr.length);

for (let i = 0; i < elementArr.length; i++)
{
     const element = elementArr[i];
     element.addEventListener('click', function() 
     {
          element.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor =  'lightgrey'; 
          for (let j = 0; j < elementArr.length; j++) 
          {
               const e = elementArr[j];
               if (element !== e) 
               {
                    e.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#ebeef0'; 
               }
          }
          
          currentElementID = parseInt(element.id);

          <?php 
            if ( isset($data['produktarray'])) 
            {
          ?> jqueryarray = <?php echo (json_encode($data['produktarray']));        
             }
          ?>;

          //alert(JSON.stringify(jqueryarray[currentElementID]));

          fillInProdukt(jqueryarray[currentElementID]);

          //document.getElementById('Menge').value = jqueryarray[currentElementID]['prodDatMenge']; 
          //document.getElementById('anzahlPfosten').value = jqueryarray[currentElementID]['prodDatAnzahlPfosten']; 
          //document.getElementById('Vermerk').value = jqueryarray[currentElementID]['prodDatVermerk'];
          //document.getElementById('Restarbeiten').value = jqueryarray[currentElementID]['prodDatRestarbeiten']; 
          //alert(jqueryarray[currentElementID]['prodDatProduktionsOrt'] );

    });

          //  document.getElementById('Vermerk').value = "Eintrag";
} // Ende Laufvar i

function fillInProdukt(produkt)
{
     const produktId = document.getElementById("produktId");
     produktId.value = produkt['id'];
     //##############################################################################
     //Produktdaten
     //##############################################################################
     //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     const ProduktionsortSelect = document.getElementById("ProduktionsortSelect");
     for (const option of ProduktionsortSelect.options) {
          if (option.label === produkt['prodDatProduktionsOrt']) {
               option.selected = 'selected';
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: *I also have a box with different products (from a products array) displayed in rows* - Do you mean that there's a table of some sort? If so, can you post the markup for that table as well? This is so that we can offer useful suggestions.

Comment: Oh, thanks for helping me. here is the markaup with php code:

Comment: I'm just checking if I understand what you're trying to do. You want to: 1) Click on the GEL 4 Füllstabgeländer 2) Fill the Produktdaten with all the information regarding the clicked row / product (Produktionsort, Produkt, Verankerung, etc). If that is what you want to do, can you tell me where are you storing the **Produktionsort** information in your table? (the one with the GEL 4 Füllstabgeländer and other products)? Can you post the generated HTML code, and the generated HTML code for your Produktdaten? You don't have to post all of it, just a sample.

Comment: Hello Fiddling away,

Comment: Hello Fiddling away, you understand it ! But the information is in a table called products. I store the value (---; DE; CZ) in a seperate column aof this table. When the user clicks onto the "Gel 4 Füllstabgeländer" - row, the data "CZ" shall compared with the values of ( $data['produktionsort'] as $produkteOrt ) . If it merged, the option wich was found will be marketd as "selected" .

Comment: Have you considered using data attributes? You could store them in your HTML table row which holds your products. For example, like this: `<tr data-produktionsort="<some_value>" data-verankerung="<another_value>" data-restarbeiten="<third_value>" ...><td>GEL 4 Füllstabgeländer</td><td>200</td>....</tr>`. You would then attach a click event handler on your table rows, which would pickup the info you need from the `tr` data set, and use it to set those values in the Produktdaten part of your screen.

Comment: Good Morning FiddlingAway, I changes the Code in the description above. I also entered the current javascript. Jörg wishes you a successful day.

Comment: I got it : <select class="form-control" id="ProduktSelect" name="Produkt">

Comment: Does that mean that you have solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, and thanks for hold hands!